# .Net Framework 3.5 replaced by .Net environment in Windows Features

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-update, .net-framework

By a recent windows update in Windows feature Net Framework 3.5 got replaced by .Net environment. Now I am not able to start applications like powershell, docker desktop etc. which relies on .NET. Here is the [New Windows Feature screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9kPU.png). Here you can find the [Old Windows Feature screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tq8ZG.png). Can someone tell what should be done? I have gone through various forums for this issue but that didn't help.

Comment: so ... have you tried doing as the dialog instructions recommend and _check the dotnet boxes to trun them on_? [*grin*]

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  The second (old) screen is what I see in Windows 10 V1909 and also in Windows 10 V2004 (not yet released)

Comment: I am using Windows 10 1909. After the recent update this .NET got corrupted. I also turned on the features by checkboxes but after opening again the Windows feature I see them disabled.

Comment: Also,  running 1909 and that new thing, you are showing,  is not something on my systems, neither is the case for insider editions.